# Debugging Python script in RAD 8.5 using Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I have a RAD 8.5 ( Eclipse version 3.6.3 ) workspace with PyDev plugin installed ( version 2.8.2 )  that I have been using to debug python scripts.

In the past, I was able to debug python scripts in the workspace.

Today, when I run the script without debug mode, it works.

But When attempting to use Debug on the same script, I get the below error.

```
Timed out after 20.0 seconds while waiting for python script to connect.
Accept timed out
```

What can I do or check so that I can debug the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you have some firewall enabled which is preventing the debugger to connect to the target (take a look at your error log to see if that's the issue... see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on getting it).

You could also try using the remote debugger with a programmatic breakpoint: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html to see if you have different results.

Comment: Thanks.  If it were the firewall problem, would that not come into play when I attempt "Run" instead of "Debug" as well or does the firewall related problem affect only when using Debug?

Comment: It's only when using debug (because a connection needs to be made from python.exe to eclipse.exe/javaw.exe).

Comment: Oh ok.  I shall take a look at the error log to see if there is some firewall enabled ( this is a work computer, so things get added without us knowing about it ).  And I shall also try the remote debugging.

Comment: I checked the above links, but that did not resolve the issue.  What I discovered was that I had set my Eclipse to use the python 2.7b4 version recently and that was causing the problem.  When I changed that back to the version 2.6, I was able to Debug.  I still don't understand why I was able to Run the script with that setting, but not Debug.